# do I have to create custom value accessors to use buttons as form controls in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm building a reactive form in angular 2, it's just a list of questions, each question has 2 buttons for answers, no right or wrong answer. example, favorite ice cream flavor? vanilla or chocolate. do I have to create custom value accessors to use buttons as form controls?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I would create a `YesNoButtonComponent` with two buttons and a custom value accessor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that for radio buttons you can apply the same `formControlName` to multiple elements, then when you click one it will assign that element's `value` to the `FormControl`.

Potential example:

```
<button type="button" formControlName="yourControl" [value]="true">Yes</button>
<button type="button" formControlName="yourControl" [value]="false">No</button>
```